# Set up a datagrid with static columns and usercontrols

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, user-controls

I have a datagrid with 3 columns. Each column contains a specific usercontrol (one has a treeview, two others have different listviews).

My xaml code

```
<DataGrid HeadersVisibility="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <view:MethodsTreeView DataContext="{Binding MethodsTreeVM}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <view:VariablesListView DataContext="{Binding VariablesListVM}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

However, it doesn't work.
The datacontexts from viewmodels of usercontrols are not even called
I know that my main view is correctly connected to its own datacontext, as it works for items outside the datagrid.

I am opened to any solution (including not using a datagrid), but this is important that I have 3 columns, and that I can resize the width of those with the mouse.

EDIT :
I found this data on Stackoverflow, added it but it doesn't change anything :

```
<Grid.Resources>
        <FrameworkElement x:Key="ProxyElement"
                     DataContext="{Binding}"/>

    </Grid.Resources>
```

```
    <DataGrid HeadersVisibility="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set the `ItemsSource` property of the `DataGrid` to an `IEnumerable` for any rows to get rendered.

If you set it to an `IEnumerable<T>` that returns 1 object of type `T` you will get a single row, if the `IEnumerable<T>` returns two objects you will get 2 rows in the DataGrid and so on.

Give the `DataGrid` and `x:Name` in the XAML markup:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg" HeadersVisibility="None" AutoGenerateColumns ...>
```

And then set its `ItemsSource` property in the code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dg.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range(0, 1); //returns an IEnumerable<int> with a single int -> one row will be rendered
    }
}
```

This should get you a single row with the two columns that you have defined in the XAML markup.